# How can i hide the URL of my frame cloak?

Tags: html, frame, frameset, cloaking

I'm quite a newbie here and I would like to ask y'all something.

I'm using this code:

```
                <frameset rows="100%,*">
                <frame src="https://accountwarehouse.jimdo.com">
                <noframes>
                    <p>
                        No Frame Support, use a different browser or update your current one.
                    </p>
                </noframes>
            </frameset>
```

I would like to hide the URL https://accountwarehouse.jimdo.com.
It's okay if it's encrypted with base64, I just want it to make unreadable for the average user.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There are certainly ways, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a good reason. Could you tell me how?